# Как побороть Unchecked overriding?

Tags: java, generics

Есть класс

```
public class Action<R extends CommonResponse>
```

В котором вызывается метод и бежит по циклу из функций

```
R response = null;
for (PreDecoder preDecoder : stateMachineContext.getPreDecoders()) {
    R preDecodedResponse = preDecoder.preDecode(request, preDecodedData.data, preDecodedData);
    if (preDecodedResponse != null) {
        response = preDecodedResponse;
        break;
    }
}
```

PreDecode - функциональный интерфейс с методом

```
<R extends CommonResponse> R preDecode(Message rqMessage, ByteBuffer data, ByteBufferRef preDecodedData);
```

Пример реализации интерфейса PreDecode

```
@Override
public CommonRS preDecode(Message rqMessage, ByteBuffer data, ByteBufferRef preDecodedData) {
    int sourceAddress = data.get() & 0xFF;
    int destinationAddress = data.get() & 0xFF;
    if (destinationAddress != (localAddress & 0xFF) || sourceAddress != (remoteAddress & 0xFF)) {
        CommonRS response = new CommonRS(rqMessage.getFunctionType());
        response.setSuccess(false);
        return response;
    }

    preDecodedData.data = data;
    return null;
}
```

В реализации интерфейса возникает Warning из-за которого maven не хочет собирать проект
**Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion. Found '...CommonRS', required 'R'**

С этим и возникает вопрос: Как собственно обойти это?

**UPD**

Если у метода preDecoder сделать возвращаемый тип CommonResponse, То в методе класса **Action** Возникнет **Unchecked cast**

Comment: Я бы убрал  **<R extends CommonResponse>**

и оставил бы только **R preDecode**

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко ну, я решил возвращать CommonResponse, а место где возникает варнинг пометил аннотацией, чтоб не проверял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что писать нужно вот так ::

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface PreDecoder<R extends CommonResponse> {

    R preDecode(Message rqMessage, ByteBuffer data, ByteBufferRef preDecodedData);

}
```

И реализация ::

```
public class PreDecoderImpl implements PreDecoder<CommonRS> {

    @Override
    public CommonRS preDecode(Message rqMessage, ByteBuffer data, ByteBufferRef preDecodedData) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не придумал ничего лучше, чем возвращать интерфейс в preDecode интерфейс **CommonResponse**, а место где выбрасывается warning пометить                 *@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")*

в итоге получилось что-то вроде того:

```
R response = null;
for (PreDecoder preDecoder : stateMachineContext.getPreDecoders()) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    R preDecodedResponse = (R) preDecoder.preDecode(request, preDecodedData.data, preDecodedData);
    if (preDecodedResponse != null) {
        response = preDecodedResponse;
        break;
    }
}
```